# how to use join in h2 database where sum function used?

Tags: database, h2

there is two table:- 1. product 2. batch
-:product  table:-(Row Count=700)
code     
--------- 
 
001
002
-:Batch  table:-(Row Count=35000)
batchno    productcode  Qty
---------     -----------      -----
B0002              001                   5   
B0003              001                  10  
B0004              001                  15  
C0005              002                  20  
C0034              002                  10  
where batch.qty  integer,product.code varchar(20),batch.product varchar(20).
This code is working in sql server 2008 but not in h2 embeded database.
every fields and its data types are same as in sql server 2008.
i want output like :-
productcode   qty
-----------         ----
001                30
002                30
please help .
thanks in advance.

i am using this query:-
 SELECT product.code,(SELECT sum(batch.qty) FROM batch WHERE batch.productcode = product.code)FROM product;

Comment: What is the result of the query for H2?

Comment: I have edited the question to show row count for respective tables.

Comment: The result output is as expected. It is showing the result but the time taken is substantially higher than expected. also, one observation I made was that the response time increased with increasing the maximum row count in the H2 Console. For showing all rows in the result H2 becomes unresponsive indefinitely.